# bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb error

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, tdd, bundler

**Versions in use:**
Rails - 3.2.13
Ruby - ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]

I ran

`$ rails generate integration_test static_pages`

and got

```
invoke  rspec
create    spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

Following the Rails Hartl Tutorial Sec 3.2.1.
**Getting the following error while running:

`$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`**

---

```
/Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:175:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError)  

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:72:in `normalize_options!'    

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:60:in `initialize'  

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1308:in `new'  

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1308:in `add_route'  

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1287:in `decomposed_match'  

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1269:in `block in match'  

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1269:in `each'  

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1269:in `match'  

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:501:in `map_method'  

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:463:in `get'  

from /Users/mwsage/rails_projects/sample_app/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in `instance_exec'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in `eval_block'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:267:in `draw'

from /Users/mwsage/rails_projects/sample_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'

from /Users/mwsage/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/mwsage/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'

from /Users/mwsage/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/mwsage/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'

from /Users/mwsage/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'

from /Users/mwsage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

---

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  # gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  # gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'
  # gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
  # gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
  # gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
  # gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

---

**static_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end

  describe "Help page" do

    it "should have the content 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      page.should have_content('Help')
    end
  end
end
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can provide other version numbers or files, just wasn't sure what to include.

---

**routes.rb (sample_app/routes.rb)**

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/home"
  get "static_pages/help"



end
```

Comment: Look at the stacktrace; the error appears to originate from your routes file. Could you post that?

Comment: @rossta        I've added the routes file to the bottom of the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your class in the `describe` section

Assuming your controller's class is `StaticPagesController`

```
describe StaticPagesController do
end
```

Or you can add `type: :controller` to the describe section like so

```
describe "foo", type: :controller do
end
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre, it turns out that I had two StaticPagesController.rb files (not the exact file name). I cleared out the entire directory and went from scratch checking the files as I progressed with no errors this time. A break between work must have complicated my directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your routes as well. I believe they look like:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
   root  'static_pages#home'
  match '/help' => 'static_pages#help',    :via => 'get'
  match '/about' => 'static_pages#about',   :via => 'get'
  match '/contact' => 'static_pages#contact', :via => 'get'
```